# Как правильно настроить .htaccess?

Tags: php

Начитавшись про единую точку входа, попробовал сделать сам. В примере был такой код настроек:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Насколько я понял, если у нас реальный путь папки или файла, то переадресация не проходит, сделано это для подгрузки картинок и прочего. Возникает вопрос. Например у меня есть файл config.ini, в котором я храню данные от БД, злоумышленник можеть просто набрать путь до этого файла и получить к нему доступ. Как нужно сделать правильно, чтобы и картинки загружались, и единая точка входа работала, и все было безопасно?

Comment: Храните config.ini за пределами сайта

Comment: поставить необходимые chmod права доступа на подобные файлы, например 0555. И сделайте config.php, тогда содержимое не выведется.

Comment: @Jean-Claude 0555 — это значит все могут читать файл

Comment: То есть это нормальная практика, когда мы можем смотреть каталоги на сайте?

Comment: @Max возможность просмотра каталогов зависит от личных хотелок владельца сайта, надо — пусть смотрят, не надо — запретить смотреть

Comment: @andreymal посмотрел в друпале. Там защита построена не только на одних правах доступа к файлу.

Comment: @Jean-Claude единственная нормальная защита — просто не хранить такие файлы в одном каталоге с сайтом.

Comment: А как можно прописать RewriteCond, чтобы не было редиректа если это существующий файл не ini или директория?

Comment: @andreymal так возрастают накладные расходы имхо, поди запомни где у кого  что хранится, перенос сайта и тд. ЦМСки, которые знаю, хранят в своей папке без проблем. А если злоумышленник загрузит скрипт на хостинг, он может подняться и по папкам выше, таких случаем сотни.

Comment: @Jean-Claude это называется не "накладные расходы", а неосиляторство :) Если руки отсохнут завести две папочки и написать README - вон из профессии, как говорится

Comment: @andreymal как говорится у кого, у тебя? ты умнее вонючего вордпресса или назвать 25 других движков, которые хранят конфиг в своей папке?

Comment: @Jean-Claude все они хранят конфиг в своей папке исключительно ради упрощения жизни неосиляторам и лентяям вроде вас. И все они действительно вонючи, кстати

Comment: Придумал такое правило, вроде как работает: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [.]ini$ [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`